# R: Code in Unicode

Tags: r, unicode

I am learning Julia and one of the appealing features of the language is that it accepts unicode characters as code.

Is there any way that R could be taught to do the same?  For example:

```
θ <- function(μ,σ) μ^σ-σ
θ(3,2)
[1] 7
```

I think this could be a feature which would be widely used.

Comment: What are the use cases for this? For instance, I see little reason in your code example to use unicode.

Comment: This works on Linux! (I'm in a UTF-8 locale)

Comment: @josilber I see several reasons: 1. for scientific work the more exactly you can represent in your code the concepts you are modelling I think the easier it is to interpret, return to, inspect etc. 2. Code can be more tersely written. I am a big believer in coding with as few symbols as as possible while still maintaining legibility. Unicode characters seems like an ideal way of accomplishing this. 3. Unicode characters might present the possibility of making space for new operators. There are not many legal characters available for use as operators in R.

Answer (score 0):

While this might work and (yes, there are use-cases) I would strongly discourage such attempts.

1. This works on some systems (Linux, probably Mac) but does not on others (Windows) thus making portability and therewith replication and transparency an issue.
2. I, for one, find it hard to read because console fonts are not made for distinguishing Greek letters and thus making it error prone.